# Do I need to wrap an Image element with a View to add margin?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I've noticed that the [Image](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html) element's style property  does allow a "padding" and "margin" attribute like the Text element and the View element. Does this means I need to always use a View with a single Image in it to add those attributes?

Comment: No need to add extra View element. You can add marginTop, marginBottom in an Image

Comment: I see. is it documented? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#style